# How to validate joomla default text editor using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla1.5

how to validate joomla default text editor on **blur** using jQuery?

This is the code what I used get text editor.

```
$editor = & JFactory::getEditor();
$editor->display('description', $this->my_data->description , 550, 400, 60, 20);
```

What I want is I want to show a warning message next to text editor saying "you can't leave this blank". I can do it in form submit but real challenge is how to do it on blur.

Comment: You're too vague, what do you actually want to achieve? If you dont spend the time creating a good question you won't get an answer... just saying.

Comment: @SMacFadyen I want to validate joomla default text editor on blur. I want users to show a warning message next to the editor if the user not enter anything in it.

Comment: Sounds very hacky. Which editor are you using? My understanding is you want validation in the content entry stage?

Comment: @SMacFadyen joomla 1.7 default editor I actually don't know the name. I have not installed any plugins for text editors. Yes you are rite, I want it in the content entry stage.

Comment: @SMacFadyen I just check the editor its tinymce.

Comment: It sounds like you need a custom component filling in the content, as I wouldn't think hacking validation into the tinyMCE is a great idea... What if they want to use it on static html pages? I would write some documentation or something for your client. Other than that, you could publish a private form on the frontend and that would be ALOT easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$js="function validateEditor(){
        var content = ".$editor->getContent('editorName').";
        if(content == '') {
           alert('Fill the description');
           return false;
        }
        return true;                 
    }";
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

Add this code in your tmpl files

and call this javascript on form submit.